# Opening mail box with html link

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

I have some requirements for my ASP.NET website like,

On clicking a button, Composing mail window should open with To, CC list and I should have a link 'Click here to send mail' in the body of the mail.

On clicking the link in mail body, Another composing mail window should open with To, cc list.

I am not supposed to use Outlook, since it is on server side.
I am not supposed to use Mailmessage and smtp, since I want to open a mail item instead of triggering a mail.

Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Sorry, but what wrong with using an SMTP server to send an email?

Comment: I don't want to trigger a mail, instead I need to open a mail item.Is that possible to open a outlook window using SMTP?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```html
<a href="mailto:recipient@domain.com?cc=other@domain.com">Email Us!</a>
```

Even you can add more details like CC,BCC,Subject or Body template,

```html
<a href="mailto:recipient@domain.com?cc=other@domain.com&bcc=hidden@domain.com&subject=Enquiry%20regarding%20product%20#0022&body=I%20would%20like%20more%20information%20on%20product%20#0022">Email Us!</a>
```

Comment: This is fine. But my requirement is like I need to have this <a> link inside the mail body. How to do that?

Comment: so you want something like, the <a> tag I've mentioned above should be rendered in mailbox, and on click of that link it should open another new mail window with TO and CC, is it?